# Magento 1.9 Table Rate Problume

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm using magento 1.9.3.I'm using table rate shipping method against weight vs destination. For 3 products in the cart  it is working fine but more than 3 three products in cart it is not calculating the table rate with product price.

Comment: Can you provide the table rates you are using for reference?
The first thing I am thinking is that no table rule is present for values bigger than the weight of the biggest value in the rates, another possible problem could be generated by some other module / setting that sets a different shipping price for quotes that contain more than 3 items.

Comment: Country Region/State Zip/Postal Code Weight (and above) Shipping Price
IND * * 10 100
IND * * 20 200
IND * * 30 300
IND * * 40 400
IND * * 50 500
IND * * 60 600
IND * * 70 700
This is what i'm using .

Comment: So what is the total weight of the 3 products that you are adding to your cart?

Comment: total wight is less than 700